# filling std::match_results manually

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I have a class that handles regular expressions but is UTF-8 aware. I want to be able to fill the standard [`std::match_result`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results) container to handle the result.

How can it be done, and is it even allowed by C++ standard?

I can't find relevant API for this task.

For example I can't find a constructor for `std::match_result` that actually allows to assign the sub_match values.

Comment: No, there are no public mutation methods for `std::match_results`. It can only be created or modified by `std::regex*` facilities.

Comment: what I suspected... also it is really mis-design by the comity